# Not all CSS files from the selected Theme are included into the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, iis-7.5

I have a ASP.NET web application that uses Themes. Inside the theme directory are 9 *.css files.

I've published the web application months ago on a IIS 7.5 (and updated regularry). If I browse the site from my computer, my private computer or some virtual machines at a hosting facility, the site will be perfectly rendered.

However, some employees of the company, that we created the page for, are recently having display issues. I was just able to reproduce the issue via a remote session and found out, that only 8 of the 9 styles in the selected Theme directory are included into the page. ([Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Developer_Toolbar) showed the this.) The client is using Internet Explorer in version 8.

The problem does not only seem to affect employees of the same company but also visitors from outside as well.

The name of the stylesheet, that is sometimes not included into the page is called `style.css`.
I've checked if the file was not accessible from the computer I created the remote session with, but that was not the case. The `style.css` file was browsable.

So far I've never had such a weird issue. Any ideas on how to fix this? For now I'd try to move the `style.css` out of the `App_Themes` directory and include it manually via the `MasterPage`.

**Update:**
I also discovered that some

```
<asp:Images ImageURl="~/images/mypic.png">
```

are also not being shown, just the red X for image not found.  Maybe that's related?
I looked for the Internet Explorer setting multimedia -> show images, it was checked.  I'll try to replace the PNG files with JPEG files for now.

Comment: Are you using any other controls (like Telerik controls or other)? IE browser has limit of 32 css files, no more can be loaded. If controls on your page are loading their own css files, you may hit that limit and then additional files will not be loaded. If that's the case, provide some more details.

Comment: @Pako: ComponentArt and the AjaxControlToolkit. I didn't know of the 32 css files limit. I guess there are still only the 9 css files mentioned above. The rest should be rendered inline css.

Comment: You can check how many css files are requested using developer toolbar, firebug or something similar. But if that's not the case, then I have no idea what could cause that beahavior, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I've done the following: I moved the styles out of the App_Themes folder and included them manually in the MasterPage.

About the picture thing: I've googled that IE sometimes does not want to show pictures that were stored in the CYMK format. I opened them with paint and resaved them, to make sure that they were in RGB. This solved at least the image issue